# Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2012 wont show in Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

The Crystal Report version i use is
SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio SP5
I downloaded it from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074

HTML CODE

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

CODE BEHIND

```
        conn.Open();
        palce dss = new palce();
        string sql = "Select * FROM [Places]";
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,conn);
        adp.Fill(dss.PlaceView);
        myCrystalReport report = new myCrystalReport();
        report.SetDataSource(dss);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

There is no runtime error but the Crystal report just wont show up in any of my browser

google chrome Version 31.0.1650.57
IE 10

I am also using built in IIS express in VS 2012

Answer (score 0):

You never load the report in code-behind

```
report.Load(Server.MapPath("ReportName.rpt"));
```

and do you have your report source in aspx?

```
<CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
        <Report FileName="FilePath\ReportName.rpt">
        </Report>
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but
i added report.Load it doesn't help any and
I attach my report source by using following code 
        myCrystalReport report = new myCrystalReport();
        report.SetDataSource(dss);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

Answer (score 0):

I just find out the cause
Crystal Reports WebForm Viewer will not work on IIS Express ( VS 2012 inproc WEB Server )

I found it from SAP official website

http://search.sap.com/notes?id=0001810196&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031383130313936

too bad for me :(